# Visual Studio - Derived Column - Destination Editor - Why Available Input Columns include the new (derived) column?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I've created a derived column FullName (FirstName + "  " + MiddleName + "  " + LastName) from AdventureWorks. 
I understand that in the Mappings section we create/check the connection between the source and the destination. But the source actually does not contain the column which I ask to derive. So why does it appear in both sides of the map?
[Mapping Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh4O1.png)
[Derived Column Editor Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyv8P.jpg)

Comment: can you please show , how you have created derived column ? Have you used derived column transformation ?

Comment: FirstName + "  " + MiddleName + "  " + LastName
I've added screenshot of the Derived Column Editor to the post too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three things:
1. Extract from source (source has: firstname, middlename, lastname)
2. Transform (Derived column adds one more column: fullname)
3. Load (Destination table)

It is step by step approach.

- so, for transformation input is Extract from source output.
- For destination input is, transformation output.

that is the reason, you are seeing additional column of transformation in the destination input. SSIS is suggesting you to create destination table with additional column:FullName. So, it is adding that to the destination.

Comment: @MichaelShuv, If it was answering your question, please mark as answer. so, it will be helpful for others in future.